# Why is nlp("hello") == nlp("hello") False?

Tags: nlp, spacy

Why doesn't Spacy implement `__eq__` inside the Doc class to compare 2 doc objects together ?

Comment: It could recursively compare two object together. That seems like a feature request.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout the spaCy architecture and how the Tokens, Docs, Spans, etc. are stored (https://spacy.io/api, focus on `StringStore`).

```
type(nlp('hello'))
```

returns `spacy.tokens.doc.Doc` object, hence in your example these objects will be just different :)

If you want to compare strings (1) use string type and don't create `Doc` objects or (2) get string representation of `Doc` using `nlp('hello').text`.

Comment: This is misleading, just saying default `__eq__` does pointer comparison is enough. Why it is not implemented to do value comparison is another question.